# How can you prevent a ContentDialog from closing on button press in WP8

Tags: windows-phone-8

In Windows Phone 8 (or 8.1), is there a way to prevent a ContentDialog from closing when the primary button is pressed under certain conditions? For example, say you have a Boolean done. When they click the primary button, I only want the ContentDialog to close if (done == true). Is this possible?

Answer (score 5):

XAML:

```
<ContentDialog
    ...
    Closing="ContentDialog_Closing">
```

C#:

```
private async void ContentDialog_Closing(ContentDialog sender, ContentDialogClosingEventArgs args)
{
    if (!CanClose)
        args.Cancel = true;
}
```